# How to add a class to body with JS?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add the class `.my-class` to body if tha class `.views-exposed-form` is present in `#navbar-collapse-second`

The code below does not work. How to correct ?

```
(function ($) {

      $('#navbar-collapse-second').hasClass('views-exposed-form' {
           $('body').addClass('my-class');
      });

})(window.jQuery);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1LvG.png)

**UPDATE**

I applied the response of **explv**.

The class is removed in `#navbar-collapse-second` when `.views-exposed-form` is available.

But impossible to apply the same rule in `#navbar-collapse-first` when `.views-manage-menu` is available.

An idea ?

```
(function ($) {

  if ($("#navbar-collapse-first .views-manage-menu").length) {
      $(".icon-navbar-first-alert").removeClass("icon-navbar-first-alert-disable");
  };

  if ($("#navbar-collapse-second .views-exposed-form").length) {
      $(".icon-navbar-second-alert").removeClass("icon-navbar-second-alert-disable");
  };

})(window.jQuery);
```

First menu :

```
<a class="navbar-toggle-first collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-first" aria-expanded="false">

  <div class="icon-navbar-first">
    <span class="fa-layers fa-3x">
      <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
      <span class="navbar-icon-open">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="navbar-icon-close">
        <i class="fas fa-times" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-navbar-first-alert icon-navbar-first-alert-disable">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <span class="navbar-icon-open">
        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="navbar-icon-close">
        <i class="fas fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>

</a>

</div>
```

Second menu :

```
<div{{ attributes }}>

<a class="navbar-toggle-second collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-second" aria-expanded="false">

  <div class="icon-navbar-second">
    <span class="fa-layers fa-3x">
      <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
      <span class="navbar-icon-open">
        <i class="fas fa-filter" data-fa-transform="shrink-9"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="navbar-icon-close">
        <i class="fas fa-times" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-navbar-second-alert icon-navbar-second-alert-disable">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <span class="navbar-icon-open">
        <i class="fas fa-filter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="navbar-icon-close">
        <i class="fas fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>

</a>

</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v3iC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz9mQ.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you add coma? .hasClass('views-exposed-form', {

Comment: @Vitalii `hasClass(className)` only takes one parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have posted won't even run, the syntax is invalid, and `hasClass(className)` only accepts one parameter, so not entirely sure what you are trying to do there.

`hasClass(className)` returns true if the element you call it on has that class, it will **not** return true if a child element has the class, which I believe is what you are trying to do here.

Assuming your HTML has this rough structure:

```
<body>
    <div id = "navbar-collapse-second">
        <div class = "views-exposed-form">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The following code should work:

```
if ($("#navbar-collapse-second .views-exposed-form").length) {
    $("body").addClass("my-class");
}
```

Explanation:

`$("#navbar-collapse-second .views-exposed-form")` will select an element with class `views-exposed-form` that is a child of the element with id `navbar-collapse-second`

If an element was found (`.length` is > 0), then we add the class to the body element:

`$("body").addClass("my-class");`

Comment: Thank you, it works. I added a screenshot to my question. I said body to simplify my question, in reality .my-class must be added to .icon-navbar-alert-disable is this possible? here is the page https://www.s1biose.com/article concerned (right menu).

Comment: Yes, instead of `$("body").addClass("my-class");` just do `$(".icon-navbar-alert-disable").addClass("my-class");`

Answer (score 0):

There is no condition in your code. Try the following:

```
if($('#navbar-collapse-second').hasClass('views-exposed-form')){
   $('body').addClass('my-class');
}
```

Comment: @drup8, Please create a fiddle of the problem.